# How to handle missing package in the MiKTeX installation?

Tags: errors, miktex

I encounter a severe problem with my MiKTeX installation related to `mwe.sty` file missing. See below a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Please anyone help me to install this package more clearly.

Comment: You can have MiKTeX install it on-the-fly. Go to `MiKTeX Options` and on the `General Tab`, at the bottom, find `Install missing packages on-the-fly` and select `Yes`. An alternative is to go to the `Package Manager` and search for the package, right click on it and install it.

Comment: what is the package name? If i press mwe its not showing anything. @azetina

Comment: I made a tutorial on YouTube about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OD15rZO_rD8

Comment: yeah thanks a lot @Dr.ManuelKuehner Its working.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for `https://www.google.de/search?q=latex+mwe.sty` you can see that `mwe.sty`belongs to the package mwe. This package is available in the MiKTeX installation, too.

Comment: Instead of searching with google you can use the MiKTeX package manager to search for a file (and install the related package).